# Kinect 4 Windows can't get time stamp

Tags: c++, time, kinect-v2

I want to get time stamp on Kinect4W

I learned some code from a blog, but it doesn't work

I want to get time stamp on Kinect4W

I learned some code from a blog, but it doesn't work

```
    IBodyFrameArrivedEventArgs* pArgs=nullptr;
    IBodyFrameReference* pFrameRef = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = pArgs->get_FrameReference(&pFrameRef);
```

> 0x00007FF748415967 There is an unhandled exception (in CZMK4Wv2.exe): 0xC000041D: An unhandled exception was encountered during the user callback. .